# Update Glassfish 4 on Centos

Tags: glassfish-4.1

I need to update Glassfish 4 which is running on Centos (CentOS release 6.7). I figured out that it must be done with the tool pkg. I have installed it but now I am getting the following error when I try to run

pkg list -u

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/glassfish4/pkg/bin/client.py", line 61, in ?
    import pkg.actions as actions
  File "/usr/glassfish4/pkg/vendor-packages/pkg/actions/__init__.py", line 59, i                                                                             n ?
    globals(), locals(), [modname])
  File "/usr/glassfish4/pkg/vendor-packages/pkg/actions/group.py", line 36, in ?
    import generic
  File "/usr/glassfish4/pkg/vendor-packages/pkg/actions/generic.py", line 45, i                                                                               ?
    import pkg.variant as variant
  File "/usr/glassfish4/pkg/vendor-packages/pkg/variant.py", line 28, in ?
    from pkg.misc import EmptyI
  File "/usr/glassfish4/pkg/vendor-packages/pkg/misc.py", line 49, in ?
    import zlib
ImportError: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directo                                                                              y
---------------------------------------------------------------
There was an error running

/usr/glassfish4/pkg/bin/../python2.4-minimal/bin/python

You are running on a 64 bit Linux distribution and the 32 bit Linux
compatibility libraries do not appear to be installed. In order to use
the Update Center tools you must install the 32 bit compatibility libraries.

On Ubuntu (and possibly other Debian based systems) please install the
ia32-libs package. On RedHat 4 (and other RPM based systems), you may
need to add multiple 'compat' runtime library packages. Please see the
Update Center Release Notes for more information
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I install the ia32-lib package?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the following libraries required by pkg using yum:

`yum install ld-linux.so.2 libstdc++.so.6 libz.so.1 libidn.so.11 libgssapi_krb5.so.2`

Then you can update your GlassFish installed components using

`pkg image-update`

Worked for me in CentOS 7

Hope it helps